# Opening specific work orders in SAP using Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui, sap-erp

I'm trying to adapt an SAP GUI script in order to open specific work orders in IW32.  I'm not very familiar with the SAP scripting language, but I've written previous macros.  Below is how I've written those:

```
Dim strArray As Variant
Dim TotalRows As Long

TotalRows = Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If (TotalRows < 2) Then GoTo Err_NoWO

strArray = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(TotalRows, 2)).Value

i = 1

For i = 1 To (TotalRows - 1)

SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtCAUFVD-AUFNR").Text = strArray(i, 1)
```

The problem is the code I'm trying to adapt is written by someone other than who I usually get it from, so I can't figure out what part is opening the work order.

```
Sub Select_WO_Ops(status, starting_pos)
    'Loop through Operations and Look for Entries NOT set
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1107/tabsTS_1100/tabpVGUE/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOVG:3010/tblSAPLCOVGTCTRL_3010").VerticalScrollbar.Position = 0 'return to starting position in table
    item_selected = False
```

I think the session.findById is opening the specific work order in IW32, but I'm not sure.  I would change this code to mirror the first example, but I think this line automatically finds the correct tab and table within the work order as well.

So how/where is this code determining which work order to open?

Comment: Step through the code using F8 and see what happens on each line.

Comment: [`session.findById` of `GuiContainer` object](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=GuiContainer%20Object&product=sap_gui_for_windows)) returns the object corresponding to the UI element identified by its ID, **it does nothing else** (it is not "opening the specific work order in `IW32`). You'll get the answer to your question by debugging.

Comment: After `SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtCAUFVD-AUFNR").Text = strArray(i, 1)` which fills the field `ctxtCAUFVD-AUFNR` (= work order) you have to press `Enter` which you would do with  `SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0` This should answer your question  _So how/where is this code determining which work order to open?_ BTW it does not make much sense to use `.maximize` in a loop.